# How to change the task scheduler in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in hadoop. I wanted to know How can I change the task scheduler in hadoop. I want to write a task scheduler and schedule the reduce task. i will be pleased if some one help me. thanks

Comment: could you explain with example  ?

Comment: I want to set and make it fix that for example reduce task with id = 1 always be on machine 2 .

Comment: Why do you need to schedule some tasks to run on a specific machine ?

Comment: I want to have fix tasks assignment to partition the keys using a new strategy.